# Failed import using amCharts5 and Nuxt 3

Tags: amcharts5, nuxt3

I am trying to implement amCharts3 in Nuxt 3 and am getting the following error in the console:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/_nuxt/@fs/Users/[...]/ui/client/node_modules/regression/dist/regression.js?v=7015616a' does not provide an export named 'default' (at RegressionSeries.ts:5:8)".

Snapshot of RegressionSeries.ts file

[image: 1]

The RegressionSeries.ts is imbedded in the amCharts module...amcharts5>.internal.charts.stock.drawing>RegressionSeries.js. Here the file which is the source of the error:

```js
import { SimpleLineSeries } from "./SimpleLineSeries";
import regression from "regression";
export class RegressionSeries extends SimpleLineSeries {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        Object.defineProperty(this, "_tag", {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: "regression"
        });
    }
    _updateSegment(index) {
        const diP1 = this._di[index]["p1"];
        const diP2 = this._di[index]["p2"];
        const series = this.get("series");
        if (series && diP1 && diP2) {
            const xAxis = series.get("xAxis");
            let x1 = this._getXValue(diP1.get("valueX"));
            let x2 = this._getXValue(diP2.get("valueX"));
            const di1 = xAxis.getSeriesItem(series, xAxis.valueToPosition(x1));
            const di2 = xAxis.getSeriesItem(series, xAxis.valueToPosition(x2));
            const field = this.get("field") + "Y";
            if (di1 && di2) {
                const dataItems = series.dataItems;
                let startIndex = dataItems.indexOf(di1);
                let endIndex = dataItems.indexOf(di2);
                let inversed = false;
                if (startIndex > endIndex) {
                    inversed = true;
                    [startIndex, endIndex] = [endIndex, startIndex];
                }
                const points = [];
                let ii = 0;
                for (let i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
                    const dataItem = dataItems[i];
                    points.push([ii, dataItem.get(field)]);
                    ii++;
                }
                const result = regression.linear(points);
                const resultPoints = result.points;
                const len = resultPoints.length;
                if (len > 1) {
                    const p1 = resultPoints[0];
                    const p2 = resultPoints[resultPoints.length - 1];
                    if (p1 && p2) {
                        let y1 = p1[1];
                        let y2 = p2[1];
                        if (inversed) {
                            [y1, y2] = [y2, y1];
                        }
                        this._setContext(diP1, "valueY", y1, true);
                        this._setContext(diP2, "valueY", y2, true);
                        this._setContext(diP1, "valueX", x1);
                        this._setContext(diP2, "valueX", x2);
                        this._positionBullets(diP1);
                        this._positionBullets(diP2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // need to override so that location would not be set
    _setXLocation() {
    }
}
Object.defineProperty(RegressionSeries, "className", {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: "RegressionSeries"
});
Object.defineProperty(RegressionSeries, "classNames", {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: SimpleLineSeries.classNames.concat([RegressionSeries.className])
});
//# sourceMappingURL=RegressionSeries.js.map
```

added the amcharts.client.ts plugin like this:

```ts
import * as am5 from '@amcharts/amcharts5'
import * as am5xy from '@amcharts/amcharts5/xy'
import * as am5radar from '@amcharts/amcharts5/radar'
import * as am5stock from '@amcharts/amcharts5/stock'
import am5themes_Animated from '@amcharts/amcharts5/themes/Animated'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    return {
        provide: {
            am5,
            am5xy,
            am5radar,
            am5stock,
            am5themes_Animated,
        },
    }
})
```

and other charts have worked, so I am fairly certain that the setup is correct.

Comment: I noticed this as well using Vite

Answer (score 0):

For those interested:

I had amCharts5 set set up for transpiling in the NuxtConfig file. Removing it resolved the error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).